# statistical model for correlated error term

Tags: error, covariance-matrix, moving-average

If I have a ($p$-dimensional) statistical model, say, $Y_i=X_i+Z_i$ with $i=1,\cdots,n$ observations, where $X_i$ is the true signal and $Z_i$ is the noise term, independent with $X_i$, and $Y_i$ is the observation.

If $Z_i$'s are iid normal (mean zero), then the covariance of $Z$ is $I_p$ (well, $\sigma^2 I_p$, assume $\sigma=1$) (and thus $cov(Y)=cov(X)+I_p$).

For example, $$I_p=\begin{bmatrix}1 & 0 &0 & 0\\0 & 1 & 0& 0\\0 & 0 & 1 & 0\\0&0&0&1\end{bmatrix}.$$

Now, if I want to impose some spatial structure to the $p$-dimensional features $1$ to $p$, say, $X^{(j)}$ is more correlated with the feature (indexed) close to it. For example,
$$\Sigma_p=\begin{bmatrix}1 & 0.5 &0.25 & 0\\0.5 & 1 & 0.5& 0.25\\0.25 & 0.5 & 1 & 0.5\\0&0.25&0.5&1\end{bmatrix}.$$

My question is: is there any statistical model that models this kind of error?

Is it something like moving average (MA(q))?

Comment: You could use a standard covariance function, such as squared exponential or Ornstein–Uhlenbeck , see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_process#Usual_covariance_functions as inspiration, and feel free to modify as you see fit.

Comment: In the case where the $p$ dimensional vector represents points on a regularly spaced 1D grid, you are essentially describing a [Gaussian Process](http://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/gaussian-process/info). As Mark notes, any covariance function that is "[kernel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_(statistics)#Kernel_functions_in_common_use)"-like will give something similar. (For a regular grid, the covariance matrix will have [Block Toeplitz](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_matrix#Block_Toeplitz_matrices) structure).

Comment: Thank you very much @GeoMatt22 ! I will study the Gaussian processes. Is that possible the covariance function if not an decreasing function of the norm of index difference. I mean, if I eventually want to model that "decay with neighbor effect" + "some butterfly effect(some far away point also have strong correlation)", it there a covariance function, or other models can deal with this?

Comment: Read this chapter http://www.gaussianprocess.org/gpml/chapters/RW4.pdf .  Bottom line is you can do whatever you want,so long as the covariance (or correlation) matrix is symmetric positive semi-definite, which the example in your question is.